# Persistent adjcacency graph index implementation

Tags: c++, graph

I have an object-based adjacency list graph that consists of `nodes` and `edges` stored in a `vector`.

```
class Graph
{
    struct NodePrivate 
    {
        QVector<int> m_FromEdges, m_ToEdges;
    };

    struct EdgePrivate
    {
        int m_iFrom, m_iFromIndex, m_iTo, m_iToIndex;
    };

    //...        
private:
    QVector<NodePrivate> m_Nodes;
    QVector<EdgePrivate> m_Edges;
};
```

In order to ensure contiguity (and constant speed) of the graph elements when removing them I do removals by swapping the last element with the one to be removed.

Now when user of the graph accesses the elements he does so via `Node` and `Edge` classes that are really just a wrapper around an index to the graph (and `int`).

```
class Item
{
    //...
private:
    int m_Index = -1; //or QSharedPointer<int>, see below
    const Graph *m_Graph = nullptr;
};

class Node : public Item {};
class Edge : public Item {};
```

By removing a `node` or an `edge` these indexes might become invalid. I would like these to be persistent and insofar have tried (successfuly) two strategies but I do not like either of them very much:

1) Track all objects of type `Node` and `Edge` by registering them and deregistering them in constructor(s) and destructor respectively. These are then used to update the internal index whenever the relevant index changes. Biggest drawback of this is quite a lot of unnecessary registered temporaries.

2) The other option is to use smart-pointer approach by having the index dynamic (`std::shared_ptr<int>`). The index is then updated through that which is arguably better than updating all objects but at the cost of dynamic memory.

Is there any other option to implement this or improve upon these two designs?

Comment: @Elyasin Well it is used for example in the context of persistent indexes to Qt models which is fairly similar concept/use so I would say it is the right word. But feel free to suggest an alternative and I would happily change it. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I must admit that I don't think this problem can be solved perfectly. If you really want to make a lot of small changes to your graphs regularly, then you should switch to storing everything in linked lists instead of arrays. Also, you can just give up and say explicitly, that all `Node` and `Edge` handles are invalidated, just like `std::vector::iterator`-s are invalidated when you add an element to `std::vector`.

### General discussion

In your case, vertices and adjacency lists are stored in arrays. Also, you have `Node` and `Edge` helpers, which allow user to point to the real nodes and edges whenever they want. I'll call them handles (they are like C++ iterators without any iteration capabilities). I see two different ways for maintaining the handles after changes.

The first way is to store direct pointer (or index) to a physical object in each handle, as you do it now. In this case you have to change all handles to an object, whenever the object is moved. That is why you absolutely must register all the handles you give away somewhere. This is exactly the first solution you suggest, and it leads to "heavy" handles: creating, deleting and copying handles becomes costly, regardless of whether any objects are actually moved.

The second way is to store pointer to some intermediate thing inside a Handle. Then make sure that this thing is *never* changed during object's lifetime, even if objects move. Clearly, the thing you point to in a handle must be something different from real physical index of your node of edge, since they change. In this approach you have to pay for indirect access each time a handle is dereferenced, so handle access becomes slightly heavier.

The second solution you propose is following this second approach. The intermediate things (which are being pointed to by your handles) are dynamically allocated `int`-s wrapped in `shared_ptr`, one never-moving `int` per object. You have to suffer at least from separate dynamic allocation (+deallocation) per each object created, also from reference counters updates. The reference counters can be easily removed: store `unique_ptr`-s in `NodePrivate` and `EdgePrivate` objects, and raw pointers in `Node` and `Edge` objects.

### New approach

The other solution following the second approach is to use IDs as intermediate things pointed to be handles. Whenever you create a node, assign it a new node ID, same for edges. Assign IDs sequentally, starting from zero. Now you can maintain bidirectional correspondence between physical indices and these IDs, and update it in *O(1)* time on a change.

```
struct NodePrivate 
{
    QVector<int> m_FromEdges, m_ToEdges;
    int id;   //getting ID by physical index
};
struct EdgePrivate
{
    int m_iFrom, m_iFromIndex, m_iTo, m_iToIndex;
    int id;   //getting ID by physical index
};

private:
QVector<NodePrivate> m_Nodes;
QVector<EdgePrivate> m_Edges;
QVector<int> m_NodeById;  //getting physical index by ID
QVector<int> m_EdgeById;  //getting physical index by ID
```

Note that these new `m_NodeById` and `m_EdgeById` vectors grow when objects are created, but do not shrink when objects are deleted. So you'll have empty cells in these arrays, which will only be deallocated when you delete your graph. So you can use this solution only if you are sure that the total amount of nodes and edges created during graph's lifetime is relatively small, since you take 4 bytes of memory per each such object.

### Improving memory consumption

You might have already noticed the similarity between the new solution just presented and the `shared_ptr`-based solution you had. In fact, if we do not distinguish C pointers and array indices, then they are the same, except for: in your solution `int`-s are allocated in heap, but in the proposed solution `int`-s are allocated in a [pool allocator](https://blog.molecular-matters.com/2012/09/17/memory-allocation-strategies-a-pool-allocator/).

A very well-known improvement to a no-free pool allocator is the technique known as '[free lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_list)', and we can apply it to the solution described above. Instead of always assigning new IDs to created objects, we allow to reuse them. In order to achieve that, we store a stack of free IDs, When an object is removed, we add its ID to this stack. When a new object is created, we take an ID for it from the stack. If stack is empty, then we assign a new ID.

```
struct EdgePrivate
{
    int m_iFrom, m_iFromIndex, m_iTo, m_iToIndex;
    int id;   //getting ID by physical index
};
private:
QVector<EdgePrivate> m_Edges;
QVector<int> m_EdgeById;    //getting physical index by ID
QVector<int> m_FreeEdgeIds; //freelist: stack of IDs to be reused
```

This improvement makes sure that memory consumption is proportional of the maximum number of objects you ever had alive simultaneously (not the total number objects created). But of course it increases memory overhead per object even further. It saves you from malloc/free cost, but you can have issues with memory fragmentation for large graphs after many operations.

Comment: The proposed solution is appealing however it would add quite significant memory overhead and more importantly it does not support removals which is not acceptable because the graph will be huge. Anyway I wonder whether the dynamic memory solution is that big of a problem. The graph will not be read contiguously anyway (it will follow edges rather than sequentially accessing nodes/edges from a vector) and overhead for allocation and indirection when dereferencing the handle seems like acceptable price for their persistance. Only question is how to "invalidate" the handles with unique ptr?

Comment: It does support removals, but each removal increases memory pool. If you are going to often change vertices/edges, this is not a good solution indeed. And in such case dynamic memory would make you suffer, because malloc/free are very costly, and you'll have to call them for each vertex created. Indirection is not such a big problem. You can invalidate handles with `unique_ptr` just like `std::vector` invalidates its iterators: no one can detect it, but subsequent dereferencing leads to undefined behavior. In order to detect, you have to use `shared_ptr` and `weak_ptr`.

Comment: I have added a new section about reducing memory cost for very dynamic graphs.